# Port is in use 50070

Tags: hadoop, centos

I am using VM with Ambari 2.2 and HDP 2.3 and installing services using Ambari user interface. Issue is NameNode not starting and log indicates error saying port is in use 50070. I tried netstat and other tools to find out if anything is running on port 50070, it is not. I also tried changing 50070 to 50071 but error remains the same except it now says port is in use 50071.Below is the error I get in ambari error file:

```
resource_management.core.exceptions.Fail: Execution of 'ambari-sudo.sh su hdfs -l -s /bin/bash -c 'ulimit -c unlimited ;  /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh --config /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf start namenode'' returned 1. starting namenode, logging to /var/log/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-namenode-hdp-m.out

2016-02-07 11:52:47,058 ERROR namenode.NameNode (NameNode.java:main(1712)) - Failed to start namenode.
java.net.BindException: Port in use: hdp-m.samitsolutions.com:50070
```

Comment: clear the /tmp directory and start the processes again.

Answer (score 0):

When using Ambari, I came across the `port is in use 50070` problem. I found it's actually caused by the mismatch of NameNode's host, not port. In sometimes, Ambari will start namenode on HostB and HostC, while your configure are HostA and HostC.

Such a situation could by caused by: [Update wrong namenode config when moving namenode](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMBARI-15126)